# Default value of functions from passed arguments

Tags: c++, function, default-value

```
double myfunc(int i, vector<custom_class>& class_vec, double x = class_vec[i].y)
{

    // do things

}
```

I would like to have the function taking a default value from the vector I am passing to it, unless I pass it a different argument, as above. Is this possible?

I understand it is easier and maybe safer(?) to do this

```
double myfunc(int i, vector<custom_class>& class_vec, double x = 0)
{

    if(x == 0) x = class_vec[i].y;

    // ... then do stuff

}
```

but indulge me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this

```
double myfunc(int i, vector<custom_class>& class_vec)
{
    return myfunc(i, class_vec, class_vec[i].y);
}

double myfunc(int i, vector<custom_class>& class_vec, double x)
{
    // do things
}
```

In other words overload your function, and have the two argument version call the three argument version with the default value.

Comment: Is there any difference in efficiency? Isn't it faster to use the simple if-statement version and avoid the extra function call? This is pretty cool tough.

Comment: Efficiency? Has anyone told you that computers are like *really* fast. Concern for efficiency is almost always spurious, write clear correct code, that's the most important thing.

Comment: But to answer the question, most compilers are going to inline the first function, so there isn't really two function calls.

Comment: Is the if version above considered bad practice / unclear ? Computers are fast, but if I have to call this function millions of time (I will perform simulation with this, so this is not a remote chance), all the little pieces adds up.

Comment: The if version assigns a special meaning to the value zero, what if you wanted to pass the value zero? Even if that is not required then it's still a 'trick' and less clear than my version. And what with branch prediction and inline functions I'm not so sure your version is more efficient than mine..